# Does Python's multiprocessing.connection serialize?

Tags: python, serialization, multiprocessing

Python's [`multiprocessing.connection` allows for a Listener-Client pattern](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection). You can choose the type of socket it uses:

- TCP socket
- Unix domain socket
- Windows named pipe

Does `connection` serialize\pickle the messages in all socket types? Or do the latter two save on time\cpu by sending native Python objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All transmission channels that can be used by `multiprocessing.Connection` (different types of sockets and pipes) work in a stream-like fashion. Hence, Python objects **must** be serialized/de-serialized (or encoded/decoded if you wish to say so) in order to be transmitted and received through these channels.

All connection types in the multiprocessing module share the methods of `_ConnectionBase`, which implements `recv()` and `send(obj)`:

```
def send(self, obj):
    """Send a (picklable) object"""
    self._check_closed()
    self._check_writable()
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    ForkingPickler(buf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL).dump(obj)
    self._send_bytes(buf.getbuffer())

def recv(self):
    """Receive a (picklable) object"""
    self._check_closed()
    self._check_readable()
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
    return pickle.loads(buf.getbuffer())
```

Here, we see that all Python objects are serialized by `pickle` using a binary protocol before being transmitted and de-serialized after being received. The actual sending/receiving is performed in the `_send_bytes` and `_recv_bytes` methods which are implemented differently for each type of transport channel.

Reference:
https://github.com/schmir/python/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py

Answer (score 2):

Some kind of serialization is necessary; separate processes cannot share Python objects directly.

> **[16.6.2.4. Connection Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#connection-objects)**
>
> Connection objects allow the sending and receiving of picklable
>   objects or strings. They can be thought of as message oriented
>   connected sockets.

Comment: Processes actually can share Python objects via [Managers](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers). Also, "picklable objects" doesn't mean they must be pickled. I'm sure they are serialized via the TCP socket, but my question is regarding the two other socket types...

Comment: Well, you asked if some kinds of connection "save on time\cpu by sending native Python objects". Managers do not share native objects, instead they provide proxy objects that forward method calls over the communication link.

Comment: Yes, I meant for [`connection.send()` and `connection.recv()`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection) however, I guess the question is also relevant for accessing data through proxy objects created by [`Managers`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers)